# R connection to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, r, azure, rodbc

Using R I am trying to connect to MS SQL 2014 on an Azure VM **(not windows authentication)**

```
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=someinternetmachine.cloudapp.net;Database=MyDatabase;Uid=MyUsername;Pwd=MyPassword;")
queryResult <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT top 10 * FROM sometable")
```

With RODBC is there anywhere to do this using just a connection string (no DSN)?

Using the above I get the below errors

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\instancename,port;database=testing;uid=abc;pwd=123456") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 6, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Specified SQL server not found.
2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\instancename,port;database=testing;uid=abc;pwd=123456") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 11001, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
3: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=servername\\instancename,port;database=testing;uid=abc;pwd=123456") :
```

ODBC connection failed

Comment: PS - I can connect fine externally using SQL Authentication by SSMS & ADO.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working with

```
driver.name <- "SQL Server"
db.name <- "master"
host.name <- "someinternetmachine.cloudapp.net"
port <- ""
server.name <- "someinternetmachine.cloudapp.net"
user.name <- "MyUsername"
pwd <- "MyPassword"
# Use a full connection string to connect 
con.text <- paste("DRIVER=", driver.name,
              ";Database=", db.name,
              ";Server=", server.name,
              ";Port=", port,
              ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP",
              ";UID=", user.name,
              ";PWD=", pwd, sep = "")

con1 <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)

res <- sqlQuery(con1, 'select * from information_schema.tables')

odbcCloseAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose public provisioning for the VM in Azure? Additionally, you need to open the ports for SQL Server in Windows Firewall (port number depends on default or named instance). Also, in case of named instance if you are using dynamic ports then SQL Browser also needs to be opened up. More information can be found in the link [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect/).

Comment: I can connect fine externally using ADO.Net - and also via SSMS.     Wish R could use ADO.Net